# iOS Safari keyboard appearence does not trigger window.resize event

Tags: javascript, ios, css

I have a layout that needs to respond to a keyboard appearnce.

- **Android (Version 6+)** - when a keyboard appear - `window.resize` triggers.
- **iOS (Version 10+)** - `window.resize` does not triggers.

I have prepared a small Demo that shows how inner height respond to the keyboard appearance. You can tap the input to bring up the keyboard.

```js
// select the paragraph element
const innerHeightParagraph = document.getElementById("inner-height")

// set the innerHeight for the first time.
innerHeightParagraph.innerText = window.innerHeight

// register resize event.
window.addEventListener('resize', function() {
  innerHeightParagraph.innerText= window.innerHeight
})
```

```css
p {
  font-size:60px; margin:0px;


}
```

```html
<h1>Current InnerHeight</h1>
<p id="inner-height"></p>
<input></input>
```

What is a suggested workaround for iOS?

Comment: It's really annoying to listen to window.resize on iOS, it will trigger sometimes because of inertia scroll but yes, it won't trigger when keyboard opens.

Comment: I am willing to listen to any idea which will help me respond to keyboard appearence

Comment: The idea is that the actual window height does not change when the keyboard opens, so you should just keep the initial height and allow scrolling.

Comment: Also, in case you don't need to change the height of your page and you just want to detect when keyboard is open, you could use the input focus. If your input is focused, the keyboard is open.

Comment: Yes, the resize event will not trigger because the innerHeight will not change when the Keyboard pops up. Do we have any proper fix instead of going for an workaround

Answer (score 4):

`window.visualViewport.addEventListener` can be used and it is triggered whenever a keyboard is shown/hidden

```
  if (window.visualViewport) {
    window.visualViewport.addEventListener("resize", () => {
      console.log("visualViewport RESIZE IS TRIGGERED");
    });
  }
```